# Website template availability

Tags: websites

Are website templates available for Ubuntu 18?

I am looking for a simple website template to share family videos & photos.

I am BRAND new to Ubuntu   :-((

So far I am enjoying it, but step leaning curve for old Windows dude

Comment: Most website templates that I'm familiar with don't care what Operating System you use. You merely must have a functioning webserver installed.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com is the Q&A site for web based applications.

Answer (score 0):

Website templates work for all OS; they are specific to the website hosting software. Ig your website is hosted outside your PC out on the web, you need to know what the requirements of the hosting company are.